# Problem with adding ppa in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ppa, openvpn

When I want to add any ppa in terminal it give me this error:

> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:flacon/ppa'.
>   
>  Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

but when I turn on openvpn I could add ppa! but I want to add ppas without turning on vpn.
what I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: unless you gave what you have tried we cant help you where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of your internet connection limitations and there is no practical workaround other than using a vpn or something like that. The main reason is that https://launchpad.net/ is not accessible from your internet connection.

Comment: Most plausible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and paste as

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flacon/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flacon
```

that will installs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was behind a proxy. I had to set both the `https_proxy` variable in `/etc/environment` (I had set `http_proxy` but forgot about https).